# What is the most successful/appropriate way to hide a string in an HTML e-mail?

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-parsing

I need to hide a 30 character string inside the HTML of an e-mail so when a user replies, their reply can be linked on our server to that 30 character string. We don't want to add the string to the subject or body of the e-mail where it's visible to the user. We also don't want to hide the text which would result in accidental selecting of the 30 character string.

**The problem:**
    Many e-mail clients (like gmail) reduce HTML e-mail content to just the basic tags, making it difficult to find a tag that can hold an arbitrary string. This means we can't create an arbitrary tag, only use standard tags.

**Our best solution:** 
    Hide the string in the "title" tag of a table in the e-mail, like this -

```
<table title="30_character_string">
```

*The solution above works in most cases. Most e-mail clients don't strip out the title tag, making it a viable option.*

**Why we're stuck:** This isn't the best solution because sometimes e-mail clients get very restrictive and eliminate even the title attribute.

**Can you help?** What is the most successful way to hide an arbitrary string in the body of an HTML e-mail? Is there a better solution for this sort of linking?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Sounds to me like all you are asking for is attainable with standard email headers (References: and Message-Id: and maybe use a unique From: address for each customer as a fallback).

Comment: Hey Tripleee, that sounds like a much better approach, I just have very limited knowledge when it comes to e-mail headers. Our entire backend is Python and after trying to play around with modifying the headers, I didn't come up with much. Do you have any resources I might be able to take a look at?

Comment: http://cr.yp.to/im.html and in particular http://cr.yp.to/immhf/thread.html

Comment: This seems like a much better approach. I'm going to dig a little deeper. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3):

If you put the value in markup, plain text replies won't work. Consider a "smallprint" section on the bottom of your email below your signature.

> Dear User,
>
> Email content
>
> Regards,
>
> Logo and such
>
> ReplyIdentifer-xxxxxxxx.

If you don't care for that, add a div to the bottom of the email (again below the sig). ANd again, it will be on the bottom of the email where the user will rarely even care to look.

```
<style>.hide{display:none;}</style>
<div style="display:none" class="hide">ReplyIdentifer-xxxxxxxx.</div>
```

In this case, you only see it if the email client removes css AND style tags.

Comment: +1; this is a good answer. Especially as this approach does **not** try to hide any information from the user (the non-html part).

Comment: @home Thanks! Additional consideration should also be made regarding spam filters. Hidden content could be misinterpreted as being malicious.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this solution will not work as Gmail does not allow <div> elements to be hidden. The identifier is visible in plain text with this method.

Comment: I would reconsider hiding it as a requirement. How would you handle plain text replies (e.g typically, mobile devices reply in plain text)? You would lose the identifier completely. That would not present the best UX if users were to lose the functionality just for using an iPhone. That's a lot of lost customers :)

Comment: Thank you for your concern. We manage text based e-mails differently than HTML. This question is specific to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Checking some HTML emails I've received & Gmail seems to allow a `<head>` tag within the e-mail HTML. You could include the info in a `<meta>` tag within the head of the email.

What type of account are you reading mail in to? If it's also Gmail, you could make use of their ability to allow [abritary strings in your emails address after a plus symbol](http://gmailblog.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html).  Override the reply-to header that you set on your out-going mail to `youraddress+uniqueID@gmail.com`

**EDIT:** Staying along the lines of e-mail headers though (which *feels* like it should be the right way to do this), if you make sure to generate a unique `Message ID` header for each copy of the mail going out, the `In-Reply-To` header that you get back should be unique to that recipient and that message. Gmail respects the Message ID header & provides the appropriate reply header in response, as should most (all?) mainstream clients/services

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately both methods will not work as meta tags are frequently eliminated and this system must work with more than just gmail.

Comment: (Just expanded this answer, though not sure if I should have created a new one instead)